# Updating textfield value using JavaScript in a form that was created using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created a form in the user's browser with JavaScript.

Later on I want to populate a field in the form with a string using JavaScript.

I have been trying the usual document.formnamehere.fieldnamehere.value = 'Foo Bar'; but it is not working. Will that only work on a form that is in the HTML of the web page rather than one that was created with JavaScript?

How can I populate the form field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you created the form via JavaScript then you should still have reference to that form input... not seeing code I guess this might not be the case but the following works: [Example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/EygJg/)

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
var text = document.createElement('input');

form.appendChild( text );
form.action = '#';

document.body.appendChild( form );

text.value = 'asdf';
```

**[update]**

if you want retrieve them via their names you could do this: [Example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/EygJg/2/)

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.name = 'someForm';
form.action = '#';

var text2 = document.createElement('input');
text2.name = 'someText';

form.appendChild( text2 );

document.body.appendChild( form );

document['someForm']['someText'].value = 'asdf2';
```

Updated to add the required attribute `action` to form element as stated by @user205376

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
    credits: subhaze
    + element reference by name
    + finally, generated fragment is valid HTML
*/

var text = document.createElement("INPUT");
text.name = "inputname";
text.type = "TEXT"; /* this is default, anyway */

var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.style.border = "thin dashed gray";
div.appendChild(text);

var form = document.createElement("FORM");
form.name = 'formname';
form.action = ''; /* required */
form.appendChild(div);
form.onsubmit = function() {
    return false
};

document.body.appendChild(form);

text.value = "LION!";

setTimeout(
    function() {
        document.formname.inputname.value = ">:3"
    }, 
    5000
);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding me in the creds, though, `text.type = 'text'` isn't required. Inputs default to type `text` http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-type-INPUT

Comment: @subhaze: true. Actually i'm failed with that valid assertion (block-level element needed around `<input>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='page'/>
<script>
    $('#page').append(
            $("<form/>").attr('name','someForm').append(
                $("<input/>").
                      attr('name','sometext').
                      attr('type','text').
                      val('asdf2')
            )
    );

</script>
```

:note I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do this and you can test it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rDthY/).